# How to add headerfile path in Cppcheck

Tags: c, misra, cppcheck

Cppcheck fails to detect a header file during analyses so it incorrectly reports a MISRA C:2012 violation of Rule 8.4. The code is written correctly (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76950275/misra-c-2012-rule-8-4-violation)) but I can't find where to add a header file or path:

[image]

How do I add a header file in CppCheck?

Comment: Related but not really a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76950275/misra-c-2012-rule-8-4-violation.